# Matlab script with functions

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to make a Matlab script with functions on it or should I use the Matlab script to call my functions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that is not possible. One can nest function definitions though.

Answer (score 2):

You should just make your matlab script call your functions. It is neater and will take no more effort. Just make sure you organise your files well if you are planning to make lots and lots of functions.